# JS confirm change to Jquery Modal Dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog

I have a modal delete confirmation now I want to change confirmation to use jQuery Modal. Here is my:

```
$('.stdelete').live("click", function() {
    var ID = $(this).attr("id");
    var uid = $("#uid").val();
    var dataString = 'msg_id='+ ID + '&uid=' + uid;

    if (confirm("Sure you want to deletes this update? There is NO undo!")) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "delete_message_ajax.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(html) {
                $("#stbody"+ID).slideUp();
            }
        });
    }
```

Anyone have an idea?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are you using jQuery UI modal or some other plugin?

Comment: I using jquery bootstrap.. Any idea ?

Comment: You should probably include that in your question and title as it is essential information.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $('.stdelete').live("click",function()  {
        var ID = $(this).attr("id");
        var uid = $("#uid").val();
        var dataString = 'msg_id='+ ID + '&uid=' + uid;
        var d = $('<div />').append('Sure you want to deletes this update? There is NO undo!').dialog({
            buttons: {
                'no': function() {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                },
                'yes': function() {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "delete_message_ajax.php",
                        data: dataString,
                        cache: false,
                        success: function(html){
                            $("#stbody"+ID).slideUp();
                        }
                    });
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                }
            }
        });
        $('body').append(d);
    });
```

Comment: How about if using jquery boostrap ?

Comment: So how can I do that if I use jquery bootstrap in your code ?